# I try change active page in jquery mobile but it does not work?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have my start page "index.html". I go to another page "notepad.html" but all what I do in tags  working for "index.html". I try change active page like this

```
 data-rel="external" onclick="$.mobile.changePage( 'notepad.html', { transition: 'slide'} );"
```

, but all does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read this thread: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-changepage-and-rel-external